# How do I force ssis package step to fail to test error handling

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an ssis package with multiple different steps and types of steps, most are not script tasks.  I want to make sure my error handling and error logging are working properly and I am wondering if there is a way which I can selectively force the package to fail at specific points to make sure it acts appropriately.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is  properties called forceExecutionValue and ForceExecutionResult for every task. Just assign a value to it